# Why Xdebug triggers only on shutdown functions and not my breakpoints in PHP?

Tags: php, xdebug

I set up Xdebug in PHP app like this:

```php
ini_set('xdebug.remote_enable', 'On');
ini_set('xdebug.remote_autostart', 'On');
ini_set('xdebug.remote_connect_back', 'Off');
ini_set('xdebug.remote_host', 'x.x.x.x');
ini_set('xdebug.remote_port', '9000');
```

and set correct settings in PhpStorm.

But my breakpoints in PhpStorm are not triggered. My functions, that registered via `register_shutdown_function()` are triggered, although I do not have breakpoints in such functions (probably because "Break at first line in PHP scripts" option in PhpStorm).

In Xdebug log I see, that Xdebug successfully connected to my IDE and get all breakpoints.

Why my breakpoints are not triggered?

Comment: No, I set explicitly remote_host of my IDE. https://2.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back

Comment: It is likely that your path mappings are not set up correct.

Comment: Path mapping is right, I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Xdebug connects to IDE before php script runs, so ini_set has no effect.
Possible solutions:

1. Define xdebug options in php.ini
2. Use `ini_set` functions, but add option `ini_set('xdebug.remote_mode', 'jit');`, so xdebug make reconnection on error or line `xdebug_break();`. After all `ini_set` put this line and xdebug make reconnection with new options, which were installed.